# Mac Pro 3,1 with no display output

Tags: hardware, mac-pro

My 2008 mac pro suddenly stopped communicating with my monitor(s) - it boots (chimes) but no signal to monitors - I have checked with multiple monitors and cables.

Have replaced the logic board, cpus, operating system (and HDD) and graphics cards but still doesn't work. Diagnostic LED 7 does not come on (GPU) showing it's not recognising the graphics card. LEDs 2,8,9 are on as usual (when diagnostic button is pressed).

Have performed reset of PRAM

My thinking is that the power supply to the PCIE slots is dodgy, but I do not know which cable this is, so I can't replace it.

Any advice would be really appreciated :).

Stay safe.

Comment: ugh, not an easy one. That's one of those times I'd like a spare machine to swap bits in & out of [which is how I keep the old 3,1s here limping along.] Do change the PRAM battery though, for the sake of a buck. They give really random issues if they're flat.

Comment: Hi Tetsujin; thanks for your advice.I replaced the PRAM battery with a new one but the problems all still persist :( .  Can you tell me which cable from the power supply powers the pcie slots - I think I'm gonna replace that and see if that works...

Comment: There's only a single multi-way comes from the PSU to the board, it's not like a regular PC with different wires going off in different directions. You can see it if you take the optical bay out, which just pulls - I honestly don't know which component goes to which, I've only ever treated them as a single unit.